# Foundry forge unit tests fail when use customERC20Token.balanceOf(msg.sender)

Tags: unittesting, foundry, forge

I have a raffle contract that required a custom ERC20 token as an entrance fee.
In Raffle contract I have the enterRaffle function:

```
   function enterRaffle() public payable {
        uint256 walletBalance = i_raffleToken.balanceOf(msg.sender);
        console.log("msg.value: ", msg.value);
        console.log("walletBalance: ", walletBalance); // this is 0 and don t know how to initliaze with some dummy tokens. vm.deal() works only for ether
        console.log("i_entranceFee: ", i_entranceFee);

        if (walletBalance < i_entranceFee) {
            revert Raffle__SendMoreToEnterRaffle();
        }
        ... other code
    }
```

My test file looks like this:

```
 ... imports

contract RaffleTest is StdCheats, Test {
    /* Errors */
    event RequestedRaffleWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event RaffleEnter(address indexed player);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed player);

    Raffle public raffle;
    HelperConfig public helperConfig;

    uint64 subscriptionId;
    bytes32 gasLane;
    uint256 automationUpdateInterval;
    uint256 raffleEntranceFee;
    uint32 callbackGasLimit;
    address vrfCoordinatorV2;

    address public PLAYER = makeAddr("player");
    uint256 public constant STARTING_USER_BALANCE = 10 ether;

    function setUp() external {
        DeployRaffle deployer = new DeployRaffle();
        (raffle, helperConfig) = deployer.run();
        vm.deal(PLAYER, STARTING_USER_BALANCE); // how do I do this for a custom token

        (
            ,
            gasLane,
            automationUpdateInterval,
            raffleEntranceFee,
            callbackGasLimit,
            vrfCoordinatorV2, // link
            // deployerKey
            ,
            ,

        ) = helperConfig.activeNetworkConfig();
    }

    /////////////////////////
    // fulfillRandomWords //
    ////////////////////////

    modifier raffleEntered() {
        vm.prank(PLAYER);
        raffle.enterRaffle{value: raffleEntranceFee}();
        vm.warp(block.timestamp + automationUpdateInterval + 1);
        vm.roll(block.number + 1);
        _;
    }

   // function that fails test because if the raffleEntered modifier
    function testFulfillRandomWordsCanOnlyBeCalledAfterPerformUpkeep()
        public
        raffleEntered
        onlyOnDeployedContracts
    {
        // Arrange
        // Act / Assert
        vm.expectRevert("nonexistent request");
        // vm.mockCall could be used here...
        VRFCoordinatorV2Mock(vrfCoordinatorV2).fulfillRandomWords(
            0,
            address(raffle)
        );

        vm.expectRevert("nonexistent request");

        VRFCoordinatorV2Mock(vrfCoordinatorV2).fulfillRandomWords(
            1,
            address(raffle)
        );
    }
```

How do I do vm.deal(PLAYER, STARTING_USER_BALANCE) for a custom ERC20 token ?

Comment: deal won't work here just mint the tokens and transfer them to the address.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work ?
I use `deal(address(_weth), seller, 10 ether);` and it works just fine!
https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/deal?highlight=deal#deal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **deal a custom erc20 token in Foundry** tests, here is the right way to do it :

```
deal(address(_weth), seller, 10 ether);
```

as seen in the foundry book:

[image: foundry - deal]

https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/deal?highlight=deal#deal

here is one of my test that works fine in my `setUp()` using it :

[image: deal working fine in setUp()]

You can use to that to *increase a balance* and you can also *decrease*. You just need to **set it to the new balance** you want. It will declare as balance **the amount you state and replace the previous one with it** (not add or substract).

Or you can just **mint some tokens** from an address that has the necessary rights (by using `vm.prank()` if needs to) and then **send it to the address you want to use** for your test.